# div causing next section to not be visible

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a div that when not commented out, does not display in Firefox but does in Chrome. When I comment it out, the content for the about section shows up. I am not clear why. If anyone can shed some light on this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

index.html sections highlighting the area that is giving me the problem.

Here it is in Chrome:
[image]

Here it is in Firefox:
[image]

```html
<div id="slash-home" class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row   no-margin-padding">
      <div class="col-sm-12   text-left ">
        <div class="content-inner">

          <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">

            </div>
            <div class="slanted-divider"></div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<section id="promo" class=" ">
  <div class="container promo-container">
    <div class="row   ">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-centered well text-center   text-left ">
        <div class="content-inner">

          <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
              <h4>Visit us Today!</h4>
              <p>Lotam tempore optio doloremque laboriosam quas, quos eaque molestias odio aut eius animi Suspendisse a elementum anteu imperdiet et maecenas eu eros non nibh aliquet iaculis..</p>
              <div class="page-scroll">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom2 text-center p-5">
                  <div id="invisible-until-hovered13">
                    <div class="btn-line3" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 3px; border-width: 1px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 7px;"></div>
                    <div class="btn-line-shift3" style="transition: none 0s ease 0s; text-align: inherit; line-height: 3px; border-width: 1px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 7px;"></div>
                  </div>
                  <!--end invisible until hovered 13 div-->
                  Contact Us</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--HERE IS WHERE I AM RUNNING INTO AN ISSUE-->

<div id="slash-home-2" class=" ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row   ">
      <div class="col-sm-12   text-left ">
        <div class="content-inner">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end #slash-home-2-->




<!-- THE ABOUT SECTION-->

<section id="about" class="pb-5  color-section2" >
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12   text-left " >
          <div class="content-inner">

                <div class="section-heading pt-5">
                        <h2>ABOUT US</h2>
                        <div class="hr"></div>
                </div>      
          </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-8   text-left " >
          <div class="content-inner">

        <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html" >
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <h3 class="about-heading">Baking Delicious cakes since 1990</h3>
                        <p>Placerat a ultricies a, posuere a nibh. Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc 
                           vel mauris ultricies, vest ibulum orci eget,Ibu lum orci eget, viverra elit. Aliquam erat volut pat phas ellus ac
                           sodales felis tiam non Doloreiur qui commolu ptatemp dolupta orem retibusam 
                           andigen Ibu lum orci eget, viverra elit. Aliquam erat volut pat phas ellus ac sodales felis tiam non metus.
                        </p>
                        <p>Placerat a ultricies a, posuere a nibh. Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc vel mauris ultricies, vest ibulum orci eget,Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc vel lorem ispuet Ibu lum orci eget, viverra elit liquam erat volut pat phas ellus ac sodales Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit uasi quidem minus id omnis.
                        </p>
          </div>
        </div>

          </div> 
        </div> 

        <div class="col-sm-4   text-left " >
          <div class="content-inner">

        <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html" >
          <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <!-- Accordion -->
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                           <!-- Question 1 -->
                           <div class="panel">
                              <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h5 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Social Responsability</a>
                                 </h5>
                              </div>
                              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                 <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p>
                                       Placerat a ultricies a, posuere a nibh. Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc vel mauris ultricies, vest ibulum orci eget. 
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- Question 2 -->
                           <div class="panel">
                              <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h5 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">Mission Statement</a>
                                 </h5>
                              </div>
                              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                 <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p>
                                       Placerat a ultricies a, posuere a nibh. Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc vel mauris ultricies, vest ibulum orci eget. 
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- Question 3 -->
                           <div class="panel">
                              <div class="panel-heading">
                                 <h5 class="panel-title">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">Value Added Services</a>
                                 </h5>
                              </div>
                              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                 <div class="panel-body">
                                    <p>
                                       Placerat a ultricies a, posuere a nibh. Fusce mollis imperdiet interdum donec eget metus auguen unc vel mauris ultricies, vest ibulum orci eget. 
                                    </p>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.accordion -->
          </div>
        </div>

         </div> 
        </div> 
        </div><!--end row-->
        </div><!--end Container-->
      </section><!--end about section-->
```

CSS

```
#slash-home,
#slash-home-2 {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 3deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 3deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 3deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 3deg);
}


#slash-home .container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}

.slash-home-2 .container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
}

/* diagonal divider */
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #slash-home {
    display: none;
  }
  .slash-home-2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your whole css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your css is causing the problem i think.

```css
#slash-home,
#slash-home-2 {
...
  float: left;
...
}
```

Remove the float or otherwise separate the `slash-home` and `slash-home-2` with a `clear:both style`

```html
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="slash-home-2" class=" ">
...
```

....

Comment: Thank you Mahabahul. This was the issue. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: happy to help :)